# Intellij Java Maven Gson import doesn't work - package doesn't exist

Tags: java, maven, gson

I want to use the gson library from com.google and tried adding it to my Maven-project via the pom, the module maven import, etc, but even though it shows up in my external libraries, Intellij tells me, that package doesn't exist. I tried reloading, restarting, removing it, invalidating the chache etc, nothing helps, can anybody help please?

```
import com.google.gson
```

and the specific errorcode:

```
Error:(9, 18) java: package com.google does not exist
```

[image]

My .pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.Avalon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Battlesheet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Avalon</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15-ea+6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>assembly.Launcher</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>assembly.Launcher</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got wrong import com.google.gson;
It's should be replaced by **import com.google.gson.*** or **import com.google.gson.Gson**, if that doesn't help, try to reimport dependencies through Maven tool, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

Hope that will help.

Comment: It actually wasn't completly right because I had to add gson to the module-info.java
But after I changed my import, Intellij provided me with that tooltip and finally it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Project Structure click on the library tab on the side. You can add or remove any libraries.

[image: Screenshot]